# ASP.NET - FLV player

Tags: asp.net, flv, embedded-flashplayer

For a company we are making 2 different sites, now one of those sites got an flv player in it and streams local flv files to the clients with the webpart from: http://www.aspnetflashvideo.com

Now on the second site we also want an flv player but this one without local files, it should stream the flv file from the other website to the users of this second website.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="ASPNetFlashVideo.NET3" Namespace="ASPNetFlashVideo" TagPrefix="ASPNetFlashVideo" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <ASPNetFlashVideo:FlashVideo ID="FlashVideo1" runat="server" 
            VideoURL="http://flv.dumpert.nl/7649709f_YTDL_1.flv.flv" >

        </ASPNetFlashVideo:FlashVideo>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this possible and how? Because it doesn't seem to work with the webpart.

Comment: What errors do you get? Looking at the documentation of the webpart that you provided it seems that it will accept a remote URL for the VideoURL property which specifies the location of the flv file: http://www.aspnetflashvideo.com/ASPNetFlashVideo/documentation/?help=ASPNetFlashVideo_Object_Reference Then scroll down to VideoURL.

Comment: I know, but atm I just run it local. And it just doesn't seem to give me any video in vs2010.

Comment: I suggest you look at the generated html and work your way back from there. The html that is produced will give you a clude as to why it is not working. Of course the implies you know the html it is supposed to produce to get it to work? If don't know that, then you need to first have that knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be completely off track here, but it looks like your Video Url has the file extension in twice... Try:

```
<ASPNetFlashVideo:FlashVideo ID="FlashVideo1" runat="server" 
        VideoURL="http://flv.dumpert.nl/7649709f_YTDL_1.flv" >
</ASPNetFlashVideo:FlashVideo>
```