# Video doesn't play in asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, video

I am using this code to play video on my asp.net page. But it's not working please help me to do this.

My partial code is here ..

```
<object width="60%" height="600px">
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    <param name="movie" value="../Help/Video/help.flv" />
    <embed src="../Help/Video/help.flv" width="100%" height="600px" 
        allowfullscreen="true"
        type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" />
</object>
```

Comment: do you see any error message ? are you sure that the video file exist and can play ?

Comment: @rom did you also check the javascript console of the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it were swf file, it would directly work for flash enabled browser, but for flv files you need to use a flv player.

[ASP.NET - FLV player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147798/asp-net-flv-player)

http://venkatb4me.wordpress.com/2011/03/13/how-to-play-flash-video-files-in-asp-net-using-c-net-or-vb-net/

Comment: Nice link thank you.. But i have one problem, Please see this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469555/aspnetflashvideo-doesnt-play-in-serverside