# ASPNetFlashVideo doesn't play in serverside

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, flash-video

Am using the below code to play the video in asp.net web application. But it runs on local machine not in server. Please help me to fix this error. In server side it is buffering not playing.

```
<ASPNetFlashVideo:FlashVideo ID="FlashVideo2" runat="server" VideoURL="~/Help/Video/Help.flv" 
    Width="100%" Height="500px" AllowFullScreen="true" Alignment="Center" EnableTheming="true"
    EolasFixEnabled="true" WindowMode="Transparent" AutoPlay="true">
</ASPNetFlashVideo:FlashVideo>
```

Comment: what control you are using. Is it opensource or it has some price and you are using trial version. Please chekc and let me know

Comment: use this http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/ its client side flash player

Comment: most of trial based controls works locally but not online you can use jw player i have used many times in my asp.net applications it worked for me and best thing is it has a front end jscript maker page http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player-setup-wizard/ you can edit skins make your own if you know css

Comment: can you send the sample code for that

Comment: http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/changeset/2316/trunk/fl5?old_path=%2F&format=zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is source code for jw player to use with asp.net you can try
http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Source-Code/JW-FLV-Player-CS.aspx

http://venkatb4me.wordpress.com/2011/03/13/how-to-play-flash-video-files-in-asp-net-using-c-net-or-vb-net/

Answer (score 1):

I tried to change the video URL on ASPNETFlashVideo

```
var myvideo;
myvideo = ASPNetMedia.FlashVideo("ID");
myvideo.PlayMedia("VideoURL");
```